# Windows ISO 8601 timestamp

Tags: windows, powershell, timestamp, iso8601

I need to convert a date in Windows PowerShell to the ISO 8601 format.

In Linux/Unix it was no problem with

```
TZ=0 date -d "<random-format>" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z
```

Now I need to do the same in Windows PowerShell. The output format on Windows is

```
Wednesday, 19. July 2017 01:06:13
```

How can I do it?

Comment: See: https://techontip.wordpress.com/2016/10/10/powershell-tip-date-formatting-iso-8601/.

Comment: `Get-Date -Format o`

Comment: Anyone know why this is not documented here?
[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

PowerShell's [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date) supports standard .NET time formats. The [`o` round-trip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) format complies with ISO 8601. Like so,

```
Get-Date -Format "o"

2017-08-15T12:10:34.4443084+03:00
```

Comment: Despite of the possible portability problem, I like this solution because it is simple and you can basically memorize it for your quickly-written scripts.

Answer (score 37):

[`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date) supports Unix formatting strings with the `-UFormat` parameter. You can reuse it:

```
Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since the question was framed in a way that suggests _portability is important_. However the implementation in Powershell is incomplete, so formatting elements like `%F` do not work, although `%T` does; nor is there any apparent way to simply specify UTC time like Unix `date` has these days.

Comment: "%F" works with PowerShell 7: `get-date -UFormat "%F"` produces the expected format.

Comment: This will give you a timestamp in the local timezone! The "Z" suffix may be incorrect.

Comment: It is incorrect, as I just both did `Get-Date -Format "o"` and `Get-Date -UFormat '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'` and got the same time, while I live at UTC+3.

Comment: @MelvinRoest In Windows PowerShell or a newer version? I just tried in WPS 5.1 on a machine with UTC+2 and it spits out local time, not universal (answer has been updated)

Comment: I used PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 12):

The following works both in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.0 on Windows/OS X:

```
 (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK")
 
 2020-12-01T22:31:41.402Z
```

If you don't want your milliseconds, then format string would be `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000K"`

Answer (score 12):

Old question but since none of the other answers has it, if you're looking for UTC, this seems to do it:

```
(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")
```

Comment: Worth noting that this works all the way back to PowerShell v1.