# Add date and time

Tags: powershell, replace

```
Get-ChildItem "\\myfileserver\files\folder\999\*" | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.Name-replace '(?<=^[^_]+)_.+?(?=\.)').Replace(".vfmpclmadj.", ".va.").Replace(".VFMP.",".va.") }
```

The above changes the file name

Before
999_837I.84146.VFMP.000000384.20210127.121415

After
999.84146.va.000000384.20210127.121415

Now I need to remove
20210127.121415

and add the current date and time.

I need help accomplishing that last piece. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append another [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operation:

```
# Remove the '.20210127.121415' suffix.
PS> '999.84146.va.000000384.20210127.121415' -replace '(\.\d+){2}$'
999.84146.va.000000384
```

Then re-append a timestamp string suffix in the same format based on the current point in time:

```
PS> '999.84146.va.000000384' + '.' + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd.HHmmss)
999.84146.va.000000384.20210127.165325  # e.g.
```

Or, preferably, as part of a single `-replace` operation:

```
'999.84146.va.000000384.20210127.121415' -replace '(\.\d+){2}$', ".$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd.HHmmss)"
```

Comment: If I wanted to change the timezone can you show what that looks like?

Comment: @user770022: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885215/45375) may help; if it doesn't, please ask a _new_ question; if so, feel free to notify me here once you've posted the new question, and I'll be happy to take a look.