# How do I fix the date format In Powershell to use ISO 8601

Tags: powershell, datetime, locale, datetime-format, iso8601

I would like to change the default format of dates and times in Powershell to use the ISO 8601 format,
so instead of displaying as `dd/mm/yyyy`, it would use `yyyy-mm-dd`

**Please note:** I do not want to have to specify anything on the date objects directly,
as this will be annoying when there is a single date field on a returned object.
I want to change the default formatting that will be used everywhere.

This is not answered by [Windows ISO 8601 timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689471/windows-iso-8601-timestamp)
The answers there all involve working on the DateTime objects directly.

```
# NOT THIS
Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

# NOR THIS
$d = Get-Date
$d.ToString('o')
```

The solution must work for Powershell 7 and above.

I have made the following attempts, but they both result in the errors shown.

### Failed to set `DateTimeFormat`

```
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat
```

Output:

```
SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "DateTimeFormat": "Instance is read-only."
```

### Failed when calling `Set-Culture`

```
Set-Culture [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
```

Output:

```
Set-Culture: Cannot bind parameter 'CultureInfo'. Cannot convert value "[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture" to type "System.Globalization.CultureInfo". Error: "Culture is not supported. (Parameter 'name')
[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture is an invalid culture identifier."
```

Comment: It is likely impossible to do this _everywhere_ with a single simple update to your session since PowerShell uses [formatting files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview?view=powershell-7.3) to determine how to display objects and any date formatting in these is going to over-ride the default you try to set elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(PowerShell 7.3.9)

My solution is to change the `LongDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern` of [`DateTimeFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=net-7.0) on current thread.

```
function Switch-DefaultTimeFormat {
    $currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
    $culture = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Clone()

    #see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=net-7.0
    $culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.fff"

    # Optional: `FullDateTimePattern` can be changed too
    #   $culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.fff"

    $currentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
    $currentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
}
```

Call this function to apply the new default date format.
Invoke the function from profile script to "make it the default".

See if it helps!

Test and output:

```
PS D:\> Get-Date

Tuesday, 14 November 2023 3:38:17 pm

PS D:\> Switch-DefaultTimeFormat
PS D:\> Get-Date

2023-11-14 15:38:17.838
```

Comment: Worked perfectly (also in 7.3.9), and TIL the `Switch` verb.
Feels like the function contents will be a good addition to my profile.